# Using the same fixers for a team (EditorConfig)

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, editorconfig

We want to have the same codestyle in a project for all developers.
So we are using a shared .EditorConfig file.
However, the decision which fixers are used in a Code Cleanup Profile seems to be stored locally, so if Developer A has 5 fixers activated, his code will still look different to the code of Developer B, who has 20 fixers activated.
Is there a solution for this problem?